# Помогите с запятыми, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация

Это было так просто, чисто(,) и(,) пусть прозвучит банально, но это было красиво.
*Здесь же нужны обе запятые, которые в скобках?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это было так просто, чисто, и пусть прозвучит банально, но это было красиво.

После И запятой нет, так как при попытке убрать "пусть прозвучит банально" нарушается логика построения предложения:" и , но это было"

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Ну да. Согласен С Людмилой.
Здесь "И" скорее усилительная частица при "пусть", а не союз, посему никакой запятой не требуется.
В этом я вижу причину, по которой не нужна запятая, а "нарушение логики"  при изъятии оборота рассаматриваю как некий признак этой причины.

Comment: Большое спасибо!